# how to drop another pin after some interval on map

Tags: iphone, ios4, dictionary

i m droping pin for current location.And also i want to drop another pin after some interval using another coordinates.Then drawing a polyline between current pin and last pin.How to do this.Help..!!!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once an annotation pin is added to map view, it will send a delegate event which you can handle by implementing

`- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views`

In the above method, create some timer which will drop your next pin.
I didn't understand what do you mean by "polyline". If you have to draw a line, implement drawRect in your custom map view class.

Answer (score 1):

You should use NSThread or sleep method to make some delay, you can add the annotation by,

```
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Here is the [sample code](http://blog.kadirpekel.com/2010/05/30/drawing_routes_onto_mkmapview_using_unofficial_google_maps_directions_api/) for drawing lines in MKMapView.